# SQL query giving invalid results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `orders` with columns like "price", "order_id", "cust_id", "product_id", "timestamp_at"

I am trying to write a SQL statement which prints out the date and total income generated for each day of the month,

My sql query is as follows

```
SELECT date, SUM(price) 
FROM orders 
GROUPBY DATE(created_timestamp_at) 
ORDER BY created_timestamp_at DESC
```

However, it gives me invalid results. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What Invalid results? Looks like a Syntax error to me! `GROUPBY` should be `GROUP BY`

Comment: Please define "invalid results".  Sample data and results would help.

Comment: Or could it be that by your own admission.... you dont have a column called `date` in that table

Comment: You also dont have a column called `created_timestamp_at` either, unless your description of your columns is also wrong

Comment: In future, if you are getting an error message PLEASE show it to us, show all of the error message, not a summary of it.

Comment: ok... sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `group by` and `select` should match.  I suspect:

```
SELECT DATE(created_timestamp_at) as date, SUM(price)
FROM orders
GROUP BY DATE(created_timestamp_at)
ORDER BY MIN(created_timestamp_at) DESC
```